# how to configure ddd to use another gdb instead of the default one

Tags: linux, gdb, debugging

I am quite new to ddd and gdb.

I have another cross-compiler, e.g. arm_gdb, how can set the ddd to use this arm_gdb instead of the default gdb?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ddd):

```
 ddd --debugger "xdb -d directory"
```

so for you

```
 ddd --debugger "arm_gdb"
```

To make it the default, consider using symlinks and / or [shell aliases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29)